# « Se sentir bien/mal/mieux… dans les/ses/ces études » : idiomaticité

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

Dans une discussion avec un utilisateur du FSE la construction « elle se sent bien dans ses études au lycée » a été utilisée, ce qui mène à la forme plus générale suivante.

- « Se sentir bien/mal/mieux… dans les/ses/ces/des études (<d'une sorte ou d'une autre>) »

Si cela était idiomatique, on pourrait alors dire ceci.

- Il se sentait mal dans des études.

Personnellement, j'hésiterais tellement à écrire ça que je m'en abstiendrais tout simplement, mais je n'ai pas le secret de l'idiomaticité, et je suis curieux de savoir ce qu'en pensent d'autres utilisateurs. Est-ce que cette famille de tournures est idiomatique ? Est-ce que certaines seulement le seraient ?

Comment: Tout à fait idiomatique et courant. Tape respectivement  *me sens bien dans mes études* et *me sens mal dans mes études* dans un moteur de recherche et tu auras quantité d'exemples. Après, chacun a ses tournures idiomatiques et est libre ou non de les employer, toue réponse ne peut qu'être subjective.

Comment: Le seul truc c'est que _des études_ dans _Il se sentait mal dans des études_ aurait tendance à appeller un complément de nom pour préciser de quelles études il s'agit: _Il se sentait mal dans des études de mécano_, par exemple.

Comment: @none Pas un seul résultat : [bien dans mes études](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bien%20dans%20mes%20%C3%A9tudes%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

Comment: @None les questions d'idiomaticités ne sont pas souvent subjectives ; on est confronté à des questions d'idiomaticité en permanence sur ce site de Français. Par exemple, il n'y a pas de doute que « l'air de la montagne le end mal » n'est pas idiomatique.

Comment: @LPH Ah bon? https://www.madmoizelle.com/se-tromper-d-orientation-conseils-9726102 exemples en moins d'1 seconde [Moi je me sens bien dans mes études j'aime bien ce que je fais ](https://fr.linkedin.com/posts/leslie-formet-%E2%98%80%EF%B8%8F-tourisme_entrepreneurs-etudes-orientation-activity-6957616426585047040-aaPB?trk=public_profile_like_view )// [Je me sens mal dans mes études supérieures, qu’est-ce qui ne va pas exactement ?](https://www.madmoizelle.com/se-tromper-d-orientation-conseils-972610)

Comment: @None Ça ne fait qu'un cas, et puis l'auteur n'est qu'une étudiante. Ce n'est pas assez pour conclure.

Comment: @LPH  Bien entendu que l'idiomaticité peut être subjective, la façon dont on parle et les structures qu'on emploie - ou n'emploie jamais bien qu'elles existent - dépend aaussi de son milieu culturel et social. La suite de ta remarque n'est pas un exemple de ce que tu viens de de dire car tu *se sentir mal* (adverbe qui modifie le verbe) est parfaitement grammatical. Par contre on dit *X me rend malade* car ici il faut un adjectif qui modifie  *me* et pas un adverbe !). Grammaticalement les 2 constructions ne sont pas semblables.

Comment: Si tu cherches dans un moteur de recherches tu en trouveras d'autres... c'est le genre de phrase (surtout « je me sens mal » - car on a plutôt tendance à se plaindre qu'à dire que tout va bien) qu'on entend entre copains ou qu'on lit dans les forums, bien sûr si tu cherches dans la littérature c'est pas tout à fait pareil...   *je me sens mal dans mon travail* (*dans mon boulot, dans ma vie, etc.*) c'est pas idiomatique pour toi non plus je suppose ?

Answer (score 3):

*Je n'ai pas le secret de l'idiomaticité.*

Merci de ton honnêteté, les preuves ne manquent pas en effet.

*Est-ce que cette famille de tournures est idiomatique ?*

Bien sûr. On peut se sentir bien, mal, mieux, moins bien, etc. dans toutes sortes de choses, ses baskets ou son lycée par exemple.

Comment: D'accord pour les baskets, le lycée ; il y a un problème avec « été », par exemple : « se sentir bien dans l'été » dévie assez de l'habituel « se sentir bien en été » pour qu'on se demande quelle peut être cette nuance que l'auteur introduit, et si vraiment il y a une idée réelle dans sa syntaxe ; on pourrait peut-être penser poétiquement, à l'extrême. « Se sentir mal en étude » ne signifie rien ou alors « étude » veut dire « période de travail dans la salle d'étude » ; il n'y a plus une relation de contenu à conteneur ; « dans » ne signifie pas « relativement ». (1/2)

Comment: Les rapports habituels manquent, d'où l'incertitude quant à l'idiomaticité. Je ne suis pas convaincu. Je n'ai aucune objection contre « elle se sentait mal relativement à ses études », mais alors que dit-on d'autre lorsque « dans » est utilisé ? (2/2)

Comment: @LPH si un certain nombre de pratiquants de la langue, qui l'ont apprise à l'école, qui la parlent depuis toujours etc etc te disent qu'ils entendent ou utilisent une certaine expression sans aucun problème, soit tu es convaincu, soit tu as un sérieux problème de ton côté. Tu n'apprendras jamais rien si tu continues à ne pas vouloir écouter ceux qui connaissent et pratiquent la langue. Tu te prends des -1 à l'envie sur toutes tes questions ou réponses, tu as un problème.

Comment: @Frank Il y a des questions, et vous ne semblez ne pas pouvoir apporter d'information intéressante à leur sujet ; d'autres aussi (nombreux, et dont je fais partie) sont dans votre cas ; la différence est qu'ils se taisent en attendant de pouvoir dire quelque chose de valable, et que vous, vous vous répandez en péroraisons qui étalent votre importance et combien il faut croire en votre infaillibilité et se faire tout petit devant votre science infuse.

Comment: @LPH Depuis quand est-ce que tu "tais" au lieu de donner des réponses fausses, de ne pas vouloir les corriger, et en plus d'insister sur le fait que les autres ont _archi-faux_?

Comment: @LPH Ta question porte sur *se sentir bien* ou alors, soit tu l'as mal posée, soit tu poses deux questions différentes. Il est évident que le jeu de prépositions utilisables avec *se sentir bien* peut varier. *Tu te sens bien en Italie*, *Tu te sens bien dans tes études* ou même  *Tu te sens bien dans ton Italie* sont idiomatiques, *Tu te sens bien dans l'Italie* ou *dans une Italie* bien moins.

Comment: @jlliagre Non, « se sentir bien (dans)» ne fait pas partie de la question, puisque c'est dans les dictionnaires (ça me semple évident). Ce que je questionne c'est la nature du nom que l'on peut utiliser. // Oui, c'est bien ça, certaines variantes deviennent incertaines.

Comment: @LPH Comprends qu'on ne peut jamais être sûr de ce qui te semble évident, ni de la pertinence de ton assurance dans un sens ou l'autre. Donc ta question ne porte ni sur *se sentir bien*, ni sur les propositions à utiliser avec, mais sur l'objet à l'origine de cette sensation ? Elle est trop ouverte pour être *répondable*.

Comment: @jlliagre Ça me semble évident (nature du nom). Je ne crois pas qu'elle soit trop ouverte pour tout le monde. Par exemple « elle ne se sent pas bien dans la réponse du maire » n'est évidemment pas idiomatique ; on n'a pas besoin de trop d'expérience de la langue pour dire ça et il s'agira bien d'une question de français qu'on peut poser ; quelqu'un y répondra. S'il y a une zone incertaine, il y aussi des gens (malheureusement peu sur ce site) plus instruits (ils lisent beaucoup plus), et à qui on peut faire confiance pour des cas  plus difficiles. On ne peut donc pas présumer de ces choses-là.

Comment: Les _moutons qui s'alignent_ manquent maintenant _d'instruction_. Ne te fais pas de souci, LPH, on te fait entièrement confiance pour les cas les plus difficiles comme les plus simples. Tu as vérifié que _présumer de_ est _idiomatique_ et certifié par le TLFi, au fait? N'oublies pas de vérifier si _présumer de_ peut être utilisé avec le _syntagme nominal_ _ces choses-là_ ou pas.

Comment: @LPH Dans ta question, l'adverbe et la prépositions varient, mais *études* est présent dans chaque exemple. Comment pourrait-on deviner qu'*études* n'est pas un présupposé de la question ?

Comment: @Frank « Présumer de qqc » n'est peut-être pas le mot ultra juste que vous exigez, mais voyons ce que vous proposez, comme vous semblez si intéressé. Au fait, auriez-vous banni Rabelais du rang de vos auteurs préférés ?

Comment: @jlliagre C'est bien ça qui me travaille, quel serait un principe qui assure plus ou moins bien la validité ou qui la dénie ? Je ne vois rien que je puisse affirmer dans un cas comme dans l'autre.